# Automatically refresh SharePoint site when item is added to a Form Library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, refresh, web-parts, form-library

I have a question about automatically refreshing a SharePoint form library any time an item is added to it.  We have a business team within our company where any individual on the team can fill out a particular InfoPath form.  Once that form is filled out and submitted, it is saved to the aforementioned SharePoint form library.

When any user submits a form like this, the other users like to know that it has happened and they almost always have their browsers open and pointed to this particular SharePoint form library.  These form submissions and the data they contain are somewhat time-critical, so it's an important way for everyone on the team to be up-to-date about the submitted information.

Does anyone know if such a workflow is possible in InfoPath?  I've Googled this issue already and I've found a lot of helpful advice about redirecting to the same page using the SPUtility class's functionality (which does seem to work), but I want to refresh/redirect the entire page, not just the pop-up window for which the SPUtility class is apparently responsible.  I've also seen some results suggest using a Content Editor web part containing some JavaScript for refreshing the page and then accessing that Content Editor via a workflow or event receiver.  Does anyone have any experience solving an issue like this or have some ideas?  I'm not looking for anyone to write the solution for me - I just need a push in the right direction from someone that's more experienced with SharePoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a bit of JavaScript that periodically redirects the page to itself. If you wanted to get flashy, you could use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx) to query the list for the last modified date of the last modified item. If that changes, refresh, or you could use the [Notifications API](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Robin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119) to show a nice 'Notification', perhaps with a refresh button that reloads the page?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andy, I did end up going with a JavaScript-driven approach using a Content Editor Web Part (with the web part being hidden and having the JavaScript in its markup).  Our customer was fine with the page reloading every five minutes to show any new entries, so I just made the JavaScript reload the page every five minutes.